# iPhone photos app 'syncing' lots and not showing photos in other apps

Tags: ios, objective-c

since updating to iOS 8.3 and probably enabling some new sort of iCloud system the image viewing app I'm working on stopped showing a lot of older images.

All my photos in the photos app showed a white circular progress indicator in the bottom right the first time I looked at the picture, which seemed related to network activity.

No idea why this was happening but those images I hadn't looked at in the photos app, and hence hadn't done their white progress indicator thing, were missing from my app. Once I'd let them do their white progress indicator thing they showed up again.

So I went through almost all my photos in the photos app to let them all get 'synced' (or whatever they're doing) so all my images would show up and then I noticed some that I'd previously 'synced' were missing again and required another 'sync' to show up again... What??

This is how I'm enumerating the images, worked fine before iOS 8.3 and this iCloud change. I tried enumerating asset groups other than SavedPhotos but that just meant nothing was found at all...

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library;
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {

    // Within the group enumeration block, filter to enumerate just photos.
    [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

    [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {
```

Has anyone else experienced this? Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: It is, I'll edit it to make it clearer

Comment: I'd posted this on a non-programming forum too in the hope someone knew what was going on from an iOS user level but wanted to post it here also to see if there were any clues from the programming side of things. Should have edited the details more though first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer on the post below seems to be the answer! 
[When can I use Photos Framework and iCloud Photo Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753485/when-can-i-use-photos-framework-and-icloud-photo-library)

Basically iCloud Photo Library by default is set to only keep thumbnails of images on your device in order to optimise storage usage. The old ALAssetsLibrary approach only enumerates photos that are fully downloaded to the device so in iOS 8 you need to use the new Photos framework instead, which will allow your app to handle downloading of the full image for those that are only a thumbnail on your device.

Quick fix is to got to the settings app and change the iCloud -> iPhoto Library settings to not optimise storage!